# NSXMLParserが期待した通りに動かない

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xml

あるサーバーでXML形式のデータを取得し、NSXMLParserでパースしたいのですが、動作している様子を感じません。パースを実行しても、ログは何も出力しませんでした。iPhone開発でNSXMLParserは使用しないべきですか？JSON形式でデータを扱う方がいいのでしょうか？

```
//controller.h
@interface HogeController : UITableViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {
NSXMLParser *_xmlParser; // 解析するもの
}


//controller.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://○○○○/index.xml"]];
    _xmlParser.delegate = self;
    [_xmlParser parse];
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"パース開始");
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"パース終了");
}
```

上記の`parserDidStartDocument`と`parserDidEndDocument`は`parse`実行しても動作しませんでした。

Comment: `- parse` メソッドはエラーでもログは出力しません。返り値を見て、もし `NO` であれば `parserError` プロパティからエラー内容を取得できます。

Comment: > Json形式でデータを扱う方がいいのでしょうか？ JSONが使えるならJSONの方が圧倒的に簡単ですよ。NSXMLParserはタグの開始や終了といったタイミングでデリゲートが呼ばれるだけで、具体的なParse処理は自分で書く必要があるので。